# Is there a boost or STL class that can wrap a member pointer if it was an member variable?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have two classes with a circular dependency problem:

- A has a member variable of class B
- B is a subclass of `vector<A>`

I originally solved this like this:

A.h:

```
#include "B.h"

class A
{
  B b;
}
```

B.h:

```
class A;

class B : public vector<A>
{
}

#include "A.h"
```

Unfortunately, if A and B are exported on Windows, MSVC chokes on not having a full definition of A when constructing B.

To resolve this I need to store a pointer to B in A. I'd like a wrapper for this, something like boost::scoped_ptr, but that creates a new object in its constructor, and has the same copy semantics as the object it points to. This would take the form:

A.h:

```
class B;

class A
{
  magic_ptr<B> b;
}
```

B.h:

```
#include "A.h"

class B : public vector<A>
{
}
```

Before I go reinventing the wheel, does anyone know if this already exists in STL or boost?

Comment: You shouldn't a) make circular dependencies b) subclass STL containers.

Comment: This isn't just a Visual C++ problem:  you cannot instantiate a container with an incomplete type; doing so yields undefined behavior.  From a best-practices perspective, you should almost assuredly not be deriving from `vector`; it has no virtual member functions, no virtual destructor, and has no protected members.  Composition is a better solution in practically every use case.

Comment: You are already reinventing the wheel into a triangular shape. See other comments and use composition ;-)

Comment: Hmm, yes you're both quite right. I've refactored this to avoid the dependency (the subclass of vector only provides a method to stream the contents, this is better implemented as a member function of A). Thanks for kicking me in the right direction...

Comment: These streaming methods may work even better as non-members. Objects are great but sometimes template functions in a namespace are better.

Comment: @AJG45 - true, in this context it does make sense for this to be a member of A (the streaming functions can be restricted to being private to A).

Answer (score 0):

Is boost::shared_ptr what you try to find?

Comment: Not quite! I suspect the answer is that there is no off-the-shelf class to do this for a reason - it's not a good design pattern!